# Converting MathType object to MathML on Mac

Tags: python, macos, mathtype

I am using the [MathType SDK](http://www.dessci.com/en/reference/sdk/) from Python to get MathML from MathType objects. In Windows, `MTXFormEqn()` can replace MathType OLE object on the clipboard with its transformed equivalent. This seems to be the standard approach.

```
lib.MTXFormSetTranslator(4, TRANSLATOR_TDL_FILENAME)
lib.MTXFormEqn(mtxfmCLIPBOARD, mtxfmTEXT, None, 0,      # source
               mtxfmCLIPBOARD, mtxfmTEXT, None, 0,      # dest
               '', None)
```

I am attempting to port this to OSX, but I can't figure out what data to pass into `MTXFormEqn()`. Calling the code above simple returns `mtOK` and `MTXFormGetStatus()` reports a generic error.

[This chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDLoc.png) suggests the source must be 'file' instead. The documentation lists "PICT" as a possible input format. `MTEquationOnClipboard()` reports a MathType clipboard object as type WMF (`2`), but I can get its `PICT` equivalent using `NSPasteboard`.

```
pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
data = pb.dataForType_(NSPICTPboardType)
```

Has anyone successfully used `MTXFormEqn()` to translate MathType objects on the Mac? I can't find any examples (in the documentation or online) which use anything expect the standard clipboard-to-clipboard method from Windows.

---

Here is a [stripped down version](http://gist.github.com/1726138) of the working Windows code. Error checking and const definitions omitted for brevity.

```
import sys
from ctypes import *

TRANSLATOR_TDL = 'MathML2 (namespace attr).tdl'

def main():
    # On OSX, use the following line instead:
    #    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('/Library/Frameworks/MT6Lib.framework/MT6Lib')
    lib = windll.LoadLibrary('MT6.dll')
    lib.MTAPIConnect(0, 30)
    lib.MTXFormSetTranslator(4, TRANSLATOR_TDL)

    eq_type = lib.MTEquationOnClipboard()
    if eq_type == 8:            # mtOLE2_EQUATION -- Windows only
        lib.MTXFormEqn(mtxfmCLIPBOARD, mtxfmTEXT, None, 0,      # source
                       mtxfmCLIPBOARD, mtxfmTEXT, None, 0,      # dest
                       '', None)
        #
        # MathML contents now on clipboard as string
        #
    elif eq_type == 2:          # mtWMF_EQUATION -- Mac OSX
        ???
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is MathType equation data on the clipboard (of any type) then

```
lib.MTXFormEqn(mtxfmCLIPBOARD, mtxfmTEXT, None, 0,      # source
               mtxfmCLIPBOARD, mtxfmTEXT, None, 0,      # dest
               '', None)
```

should work on either platform (Mac or Win). How are you getting the MT eqn data on to the clipboard? Do you have a way to tell What is actually on the clipboard when you call MTXFormEqn?

Comment: I used the MathType editor to copy an equation to the system clipboard. Calling `MTEquationOnClipboard()` reports the data as type `2` -- `mtWMF_EQUATION`. This can be converted to a "PICT" object using `NSPasteboard`, but I don't know how to pass that to `MTXFormEqn()`.
On Windows it's easy -- run `MTXFormEqn()` with a destination of clipboard, and  the MathML is on the clipboard. On OSX, the original clipboard data remains unchanged.

Comment: MTEquationOnClipboard returning mtWMF_EQUATION is a bug. There are no WMF's on Mac, what's on the clipboard is actually a PICT. I don't understand why calling MTXFormEqn (with source = mtxfmCLIPBOARD) is failing. I'll see if I can duplicate what your seeing (or better yet put together a code snippet that works).

Comment: Here's a bare-bones example. http://gist.github.com/1726138 Start with a MathType object on the clipboard. After running in Windows, I get MathML on the clipboard. On OSX, the MathType object remains on the clipboard. Can you duplicate this behavior?

Comment: Update: I also added the output of `NSPasteboard.types()` to the gist. https://gist.github.com/1726138#file_pasteboard_types.py Type PICT is clearly there. Could the clipboard-to-clipboard operation be failing because `MTEquationOnClipboard()` is reporting `mtWMF_EQUATION` instead of `mtMAC_PICT_EQUATION`?

Comment: No MTXFormEqn does not call MTEquationOnClipboard, so the fact that MTEquationOnClipboard is returning mtWMF_EQUATION does not matter. The call to MTXFormEqn will look for any MathType eqn data on the clipboard. Your list of clipboard types, indicates that MathType was the app that placed the data on the clipboard ("CorePasteboardFlavorType 0x45514E44" is 'EQND', MathTypes native eqn data format). Given that EQND is on the clipboard MTXFormEqn should just use that (i.e. not even bother with the PICT). I see no reason why MTXFormEqn should fail.

Comment: I haven't been able to dupblicate your results yet. I need some assistance in setting up your example on my Mac, but our local Mac guru has been out sick. Sorry for the delay, but it may have to wait until Monday.

Comment: I am able to reproduce your results. I can see that MathType is successfully getting the equation from the clipboard and translating it to MathML. The problem seems to be in MT6Lib; it succeeds in getting the MathML text from MathType and puts the text on the clipboard (or at least attempts to), but for some reason it's not showing up there. I'm still investigating.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to reproduce this. Thank you for your continued help.

Comment: Bad news (maybe). Evidently there is a Python bug that causes PutScrapFlavor (the function MT6Lib uses to put stuff on the Mac clipboard) to fail.  Check out: http://bugs.python.org/issue1700507 Not absolutely sure that this is the source of the problem, but it matches what I am seeing. I'm looking for a workaround.